# possible to create Joomla user that is not automatically activated?

Tags: profile, joomla, registration, user-account, user

I have set up a profile that includes fields to create a Joomla user. That works -- when the profile is submitted, the user is created. However, that user is created as enabled, so they can log in to the website immediately.

Based on my testing, it seems CiviCRM does not respect the "new users must be approved by admin" setting in Joomla.  Is there a way to set up the system where the Joomla user is automatically created, but in a "disabled" state?  I need for an administrator to approve each new user before they can log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this to apply for all the registrations you can do it the following way

Create a new user group and assign public as parent

and then add new users to the above group upon registration

afterwards your admin can go and move the user from public group to a registered group.

I haven't tested this but it should work

Comment: Super! That's exactly what I was looking for.